# C#: Parameterless methods and value variable

Tags: c#

While creating a Property in C#:

```
class Person
{
  private string name; // field

  public string Name   // property
  {
    get { return name; }   // get method
    set { name = value; }  // set method
  }
}
```

Regarding the accessor/mutator methods, get and set:
What is the term of a "parameterless" methods such as these?

Regarding the never (manually) defined variable/parameter "value":
What is the term of such a variable?

Comment: property?  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties)

Comment: Microsoft also has a doc-page about [value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value)

Comment: @Luuk - wouldn't it be better if you place the links in an answer, just to signal others that this post is "done"?

Comment: I added an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsoft has great documentation about C#

- property is explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties
- value is explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value

A (start) page with the C# documentation is also available here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/